# Wordpress add_menu_page include a php page from theme directory

Tags: wordpress

I have added some custom tables to a wordpress and trying to add wp-admin section to manage them. By using following code I have successfully added a menu item in wp-admin but I'm unable to call the php page that resides into my theme folder

```
add_menu_page('Private Messages', 'Private Messages', 'manage_options',
              'message_admin', 'message-admin.php',
               get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/style/images/message.png');
```

in error_log it gives me this error

> PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'message-admin.php' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/idon.dev/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 470, referer: http://idon.dev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=message_admin

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
    function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
     {
              add_menu_page( 'Private Messages', 'Private Messages', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php','', plugins_url( 'myplugin/style/images/message.png' ), 6 );
     }
?>
 /plugin/myplugin/myplugin-admin.php

 <?php
 echo "My pLugin"
 ?>
```

Comment: I already know that, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page#Examples

Answer (score 0):

call some function from another file into `add_menu_page()`

if your plugin structure's like :

```
. /my-plugin/
  .. /includes/
    ... add_menu_page.php
    ... function_menu_page.php
```

then you can add `myFunc()` into `function_menu_page.php` :

```php
function myFunc($string) { return $string;  //returns the argument passed into the function }
```

finally call `add_menu_page()` like this :

```php
add_menu_page(
    'my page', // Page Title or $page_title
    'title of my page', // Menu Title or $menu_title
    'manage_options', // Capabiliy or $capability
    'import_php/index.php', // Menu_slug or $menu_slug
    'getmyFunc', // function
    'dashicons-tickets', // icon_url or $icon_url
    6   // position or $position
);

include 'function_menu_page.php'; // Note : you need to include your Alt file there !

function getmyFunc() { echo myFunc("hello from function_menu_page.php"); }
```